# Draw a circle in a syntactic tree (tikzpicture)

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, circles

How could I draw a circle that contains both phi and T?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzset{sibling distance=5em}
\node (top) {}
child[blue] {node {$\phi$}}
child [blue] {node  {}
child [blue]{node {T}}
child {node {}
child[red] {node {Mood}}
child [red]{node {}
child {node {Asp}}
child {node {}
child {node {Cause}}
child {node {Proc}}
}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzset{sibling distance=5em}
\draw[blue] (-.5,-2.2) circle (40pt);
\node (top) {}
child[blue] {node {$\phi$}} 
child [blue] {node  {}
child [blue]{node {T}}
child {node {}
child[red] {node {Mood}}
child [red]{node {}
child {node {Asp}}
child {node {}
child {node {Cause}}
child {node {Proc}}
}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or with a dotted circle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzset{sibling distance=5em}
\draw[blue, dotted] (-.5,-2.2) circle (40pt);
\node (top) {}
child[blue] {node {$\phi$}} 
child [blue] {node  {}
child [blue]{node {T}}
child {node {}
child[red] {node {Mood}}
child [red]{node {}
child {node {Asp}}
child {node {}
child {node {Cause}}
child {node {Proc}}
}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]